# Checking substrings in array and replacing them in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm asked to write a program that replaces words in the array `test_tweets` that match words in the `banned_phrases` array with `"CENSORED"`.

```
test_tweets = [
  "This politician sucks!",
  "I hate this Government!",
  "I can't believe we're living with such a bad politician. We were so foolish",
  "Politicianname is a danger to society. I hate that he's so bad – it sucks."
  ]

banned_phrases = ["sucks", "bad", "hate", "foolish", "danger to society"]
```

I can't figure out what method achieves this.

Comment: How would I replace the words in 'test_tweets' that match 'banned_phrases' with "CENSORED"?

Comment: Do you want to filter, and then replace? Filtering means to remove, which makes replacing not make sense.

Comment: sorry, I just mean replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `map` + `inject`:

```
filtered = test_tweets.map do |tweet|
  banned_phrases.inject(tweet) do |r, phrase|
    r.gsub phrase, 'CENSORED'
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
re = Regexp.union(banned_phrases)
# => /sucks|bad|hate|foolish|danger\ to\ society/
test_tweets.map{|s| s.gsub(re, "CENSORED")}
```

The outputs is:

```
[
  "This politician CENSORED!",
  "I CENSORED this Government!",
  "I can't believe we're living with such a CENSORED politician. We were so CENSORED",
  "Politicianname is a CENSORED. I CENSORED that he's so CENSORED – it CENSORED."
]
```